# NSString replace escaped characters with original version e.g. %40 with @

Tags: ios7

the web service I'm connecting to returns NSString with escaped characters in it e.g. @ Painful will be returned as %40+Painful

Is there a way to replace %40 with it's original @ which I need to do before displaying in the app

Note: am working on iOS7

Comment: Perhaps you could consider using the routine in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673207/c-c-url-decode-library

Answer (score 0):

as with  so many problems, the solution turned out to be simpler that I believed it would...

```
    NSString *s = [@"%40 Painful" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
    s = [s stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //This give s=@ Painful
```

thanks Apple!