# Parse a HTTP URL using C/ C++

Tags: c++, c, parsing

I have this URL-request string coming as input:

```
url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ohmert.com%2Fopencar%2Ffetch-examples%2Fexample-fetch.json
```

Using C or C++ I need to parse this and get the output as

```
http://www.ohmert.com//opencar/fetch-examples/example-fetch.json
```

Please respond as to how I can achieve this.

Comment: This could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673207/c-c-url-decode-library

Comment: Surely the double slashes in your 'desired' output are a mistake?

Comment: @Jongware . Yup !! thats a typing error

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the complementary functions ...

- [curl_easy_escape](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html)
- [curl_easy_unescape](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_unescape.html)

... the latter does exactly what you want.