# CPP + Regular Expression to Validate URL

Tags: c++, c, regex, mfc, visual-c++

I want to build a regular expression in c++{MFC} which validates the URL.

The regular expression must satisfy following conditions.

Valid URL:-
http://cu-241.dell-tech.co.in/MyWebSite/ISAPIWEBSITE/Denypage.aspx/
http://www.google.com
http://www.google.co.in

Invalid URL:-

1. http://cu-241.dell-tech.co.in/\MyWebSite/\ISAPIWEBSITE/\Denypage.aspx/ = Regx must check & invalid URL as '\' character between "/\MyWebSite/\ISAPIWEBSITE/\Denypage.aspx/"
2. http://cu-241.dell-tech.co.in//////MyWebSite/ISAPIWEBSITE/Denypage.aspx/ = Regx must check & invalidate URL due to multiple entries of "///////" in url.
3. http://news.google.co.in/%5Cnwshp?hl=en&tab=wn = Regex must check & invalidate URL for additional insertion of %5C & %2F character.

How can we develop a generic Regular Expression satisfying above condition.
Please, Help us by providing a regular expression that will handle above scenario's in CPP{MFC}

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried using the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-50) suggestion? If you're capable of using GCC-4.9 then you can go directly with `<regex>`.

It states that with `^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?` you can get as submatches:

```
  scheme    = $2
  authority = $4
  path      = $5
  query     = $7
  fragment  = $9
```

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::string url (argv[1]);
  unsigned counter = 0;

  std::regex url_regex (
    R"(^(([^:\/?#]+):)?(//([^\/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?)",
    std::regex::extended
  );
  std::smatch url_match_result;

  std::cout << "Checking: " << url << std::endl;

  if (std::regex_match(url, url_match_result, url_regex)) {
    for (const auto& res : url_match_result) {
      std::cout << counter++ << ": " << res << std::endl;
    }
  } else {
    std::cerr << "Malformed url." << std::endl;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Then:

```
./url-matcher http://localhost.com/path\?hue\=br\#cool

Checking: http://localhost.com/path?hue=br#cool
0: http://localhost.com/path?hue=br#cool
1: http:
2: http
3: //localhost.com
4: localhost.com
5: /path
6: ?hue=br
7: hue=br
8: #cool
9: cool
```

Comment: This is working really great. Could you show me how to use this to extract all matching urls in a string using the regex? I tried to use it with sregex_iterator but I don't get any matches. Thank you very much!

Comment: Unforutnately this is not for validating but for splitting a correct URI into its parts.  It will not even detect the most simple cases, like unencoded spaces.

Comment: Thanks for such a useful and well-explained answer. This is the best all-around URL parsing script I've found for accuracy, ease of use, and quickness of implementation. And you don't need to download any special libraries! It would make a great answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2616011/1043704

Comment: Note that if a port is present, it will be included in elements 3 and 4. I.e., `http://localhost.com:8888/path?hue=br#cool` results in `3: //localhost.com:8888` and `4: localhost.com:8888`.

Comment: not working, "aaa" will be accepted by this expression

Answer (score 0):

look at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, there is a community tab on the right where you find contributed regex's. There is a URI category, not sure you'll find exactly what you need but this is a good start

Answer (score 0):

With the following regex you can filter out simply most of the incorrect URLs:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::string url(argv[1]);
    std::regex urlRegex(R"(^https?://[0-9a-z\.-]+(:[1-9][0-9]*)?(/[^\s]*)*$)");

    if (!std::regex_match(value, urlRegex)) {
        throw Poco::InvalidArgumentException(
            "Malformed URL: \"" + value + "\". "
            "The URL must start with http:// or https://, "
            "the domain name should only contain lowercase alphanumeric characters, '.' and '-', "
            "the port should not start with 0, "
            "and the URL should not contain any whitespace.");
    }
}
```

It checks if the URL starts with `http://` or `https://`, whether the domain name is only `lowercase alphanumeric characters` with `'.'` and `'-'`, checks that the port is not starting with 0 (e.g. 0123), and allows for any port number and any path/query string that does not contain whitespace.

But to be absolutely sure that the URL is valid, you're probably better off parsing the URL. I would not recommend  trying to cover all scenarios with regex (including the correctness of paths, queries, fragments), because it would be pretty difficult.