# cross--platform URI handling library for C++

Tags: c++, url, uri

I am looking for a C++ library to handle URLs/URIs, mainly HTTP URLs. I only want the URI text handling, not any network operation. I know of [Poco::URI](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.URI.html) but IIRC one has to use the whole framework for it to work properly, so I would prefer something smaller and/or standalone. Is there any such other thing?

Comment: What options did [Google](https://www.google.com/#output=search&q=C%2B%2B+parse+uri) give you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to parse a url in C++ cross platform?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616011/easy-way-to-parse-a-url-in-c-cross-platform)

Answer (score 0):

Boost.Spirit, released under the Boost Software License allows you to do this. The library is cpp-netlib which you can find the documentation for at http://cpp-netlib.github.com/ .

The relevant type you'll want to use is `boost::network::http::uri` .