# Regex error with boost

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm trying to match a string who looks like:

`/new-contact?id=nb&name=test` or  `/new-contact?id=nb`

Basically the number of arguments is undefined.

so I have tried this regular expression:

```
boost::regex re("^/new-contact\\?(([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&?)+$");
```

but when I try to use re with the following function:

```
function test()
{
    std::string input("/new-contact?id=5&name=Test");
    boost:cmatch token;
    boost::regex_match(req.c_str(), token, input);
    std::cout << token[1] << std::endl;
}
```

I get

```
output: name=Test
```

and if I change the input string to

```
std::string input("/new-contact?id=5&");
```

I get

```
output: id=5
```

I guess I am only getting the last token but I am suppose to get everything with the last "+" ?

What did I miss?

It's now working with:

```
^/new-contact\\?((([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)&?)+)$
```

Comment: did you try regex_iterator?

Comment: It's only a little part of the program that's why I need regex_match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`token[0]` is going to contain the entire match. Subsequent indices give you the sub-tokens of the match, which are determined by the parenthesis in your expression (parenthesized groups are called *capturing groups*; use `(?:...)` for non-capturing groups).

This is documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html). Copying the provided example,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;

regex expression("([0-9]+)(\\-| |$)(.*)");

// process_ftp: 
// on success returns the ftp response code, and fills 
// msg with the ftp response message. 
int process_ftp(const char* response, std::string* msg)
{
   cmatch what;
   if(regex_match(response, what, expression))
   {
      // what[0] contains the whole string 
      // what[1] contains the response code 
      // what[2] contains the separator character 
      // what[3] contains the text message. 
      if(msg)
         msg->assign(what[3].first, what[3].second);
      return std::atoi(what[1].first);
   }
   // failure did not match 
   if(msg)
      msg->erase();
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the part with the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that regular expressions are the wrong tool for parsing URL paths. May I suggest an [URL parsing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616011/easy-way-to-parse-a-url-in-c-cross-platform)?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using other library (I will change boost for std after)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the continuation escape `\G`:

```
^/new-contact\\?|(?>\\G([^=]+)=([^&]+)&?)+
```