# C APIs for mailto url parsing

Tags: c, linux

Is there a known standard technique to parse a `mailto` URL string into components using a `C` program? Or should I do it manually using `C` string library with my own logic?

> mailto:someone@example.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&cc=someone_else@example.com&body=This%20is%20the%20body

Is there a way to do it using regex APIs?

Comment: since you mentionned c++ in your tags, Boost has a regex module which can be used to validate emails: http://www.codeobsessed.com/code/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=156

Comment: @georgesl c++11 has regex, no need for Boost, however using regex to validate email addresses comes with plenty of issues - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) for more details.

Comment: @msam not all compilers (g++, sigh) implement regex in a usable way.

Comment: I am looking for C implementation. Removed C++ from tag

Comment: [this](http://www.w3.org/Library/src/HTParse.c) might be at least partially useful if you don't find anything else

Comment: Isn't this nice exercise how to use lexx & yacc?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, C or C++? I assume you're working in C++. If so, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2616011/2006222) post.
It mentions a library called [cpp-netlib](http://cpp-netlib.org/), which contains a class named [uri](http://cpp-netlib.org/0.10.1/in_depth/uri.html). It should suit your purposes.

Comment: I am looking for C implementation. Removed C++ from tag

Comment: @Bose I'm confused. Do you need C or C++?

Comment: @Bose Take a look at [uriparser](http://uriparser.sourceforge.net/). It claims to abide strictly by [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986), which describes the `mailto:` URI scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strstr` to search for `mailto:` and take the characters you want.

Here's an example:

```
char *mailto = strstr( str, "mailto:" );

char *qm = strchr( mailto, '?' );

char *email = mailto + strlen("mailto:");

*qm = '\0';
```

You can take the other components using the same thing. The email should point to someone@example.com. This will modify the input string though.

Comment: This is how I am planning to do, but just was wondering if there are standard library APIs are available for the same purpose.