# Check a Location/Path

Tags: c++

i'm really new on C++ and i want to try a little bit C++. Normally i'm come from Java/PHP.

I have a String like;

```
std::string location = "file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Demo/";
```

or

```
std::string location = "http://www.example.com/site.php";
```

How i can check:

- **a** has `location` the domain `www.example.com` or `example1.com`
- **b** starts the domain with `http://` or `https://`

In Java or PHP i would take Regular Expression. But simply no idea how to start in C++.

My first things was to check `http://`:

```
std::string location = "";

if (strncmp(location.c_str(), "http://", 7)) {
    /* yepp */
} else {
    /* nope */
}
```

But that won't work.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Maybe try [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)?

Comment: By the way, strncmp doesn't return `bool`.  It returns 0 on a match.

Comment: oh, thanks for the answers. `strncmp() == 0` is true, right? Thanks for the link. I try to play a little bit with that.

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ doesn't come with "batteries included" as opposed to Java or PHP. Perhaps you can explore the regex functions linked above (only available in C++11 and not well supported yet), or use the standard string functions. For C++11 regex support, perhaps Boost can serve as a replacement.

Comment: @yjwong The batteries come in a separate package: http://www.boost.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll attack your question in three ways, from most to least specific.

1 - Instead of reinventing the wheel, you can opt for suggestions already given here on Stack Overflow:

[Easy way to parse a url in C++ cross platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616011/easy-way-to-parse-a-url-in-c-cross-platform)

2 - Regexps are indeed fully supported in C++. You might refer to the following as a start:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/

3 - In general, it is not advisable to utilize C-style functions such as strncmp to compare strings. The std::string class has several substring search functions that you'd best be using. The most basic of them is the following:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Hope this helps you get on the right track regardless of how you choose to proceed.

Comment: Not a problem. BTW, yjwong is correct in saying that the functions in <regex> may not be supported in your compiler. In that case, you may need to download the Boost libraries as yjwong suggested. For more information, go to http://www.boost.org/. It is probably a good idea to have the latest of these libraries on hand anyway even if you do have it built-in to your compiler.

Comment: Okay, it's to complex for a newby to download thirdparty libs. Want methods that generally I can use. Your first link is awesome!