# Convert URI to path

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am working on a Windows C++ App, where I get a URI similar to `file:///C:/test 1/file.foo`. Now I want to e.g. open that URI with `ifstream`.

Is there any C/C++ API available on Windows to convert such a path?

My Google Foo seems to be weak today.

Comment: Just remove the `"file:///"` part? Or get a substring of the rest? And if the URI doesn't start with `"file:///"` then it's not something that should be opened as a file anyway.

Comment: And then there is `%` escaping and perhaps existence check. It is not as easy as you think it is.

Comment: There are lots of libraries and functions around that will decode URIs. I cannot believe that you can't find one. Question must have been asked here loads of times. Search harder.

Comment: one possibility: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773581(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616011/easy-way-to-parse-a-url-in-c-cross-platform

Comment: This link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616011/easy-way-to-parse-a-url-in-c-cross-platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616011/easy-way-to-parse-a-url-in-c-cross-platform) was in a comment, and I found it helpful.

Comment: adding helpful comment as an answer seems difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [multiple](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freeassociations/2005/05/19/the-bizarre-and-unhappy-story-of-file-urls/) file URI "versions" so you should not [parse](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/) it yourself, some of [the APIs are broken](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/09/13/createurlmoniker-considered-harmful/) as well.

If you just want a Windows style path, call [`PathCreateFromUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773581(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you don't want to convert the path then you must use `CreateURLMonikerEx` or `SHParseDisplayName` (with a bind context) but then you end up with a Windows `IStream` instead.

Answer (score 2):

There is **PathCreateFromUrl()** :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773581(v=vs.85).aspx