# How to parse HTTP parameters?

Tags: c++, http, parsing, parameters

I'm in a web server project with a mate developing everything from 0.

We are doing pretty well so far. Now we are working into the http parameters parser and got stuck.

What i want to do:
Parse the http parameters from the url and the request body (POST parameters).

How should they look:

```
http.urlParams = { "key:value", "key:value", ... }

http.postParams = { "key:value", "key:value", ... }
```

What i got:

```
http.action = "example.php"
http.rawUrlParams = "name=manolo&age=26";
http.rawPostParams = "user=manolo&password=12345678";
```

Problems:

- I don't know how to handle that url params can have every caracter.
  Example: https://example.com/index.php?question=how_are_you?&response=good==true&&fine=true&xD&xD2=&example&&&??&

Questions:

- Is there any set of instructions about how i should make the parser?
- Do you know any function that does just that?
- Should i be concerned about something i'm missing?

Misc:
I'm expecting browsers as http clients.

I'm doing everything from cero, so pls don't send me a lib that weigths 20 times my server size just for parse parameters.

Don't send me links without code explanation.

Comment: post what you have tried so far

Comment: How is this a cpp question?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're reinventing the wheel? You could use [Poco](https://pocoproject.org/)

Comment: Here is a way with std::regex : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53526139/2193968