# How to combine two relative URIs into one in C++

Tags: c++, networking, uri

I have one base URI like `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` and a relative URI.
I want to combine them all into one absolute URI.

Examples:

- Relative URI: `../`

  Result: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions`
- Relative URI: `/abc/kk?6`

  Result: `https://stackoverflow.com/abc/kk?6`
- Relative URI: `task.php?ui=4`

  Result: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/task.php?ui=4`

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code.

Comment: C++ does not have URL parsing capability. Do you have a specific 3rd-party library in mind? After you parsed the URL, you can use `std::filesystem::path` capabilities to combine the path parts (simply the `/` operator).

Comment: You can check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616011/easy-way-to-parse-a-url-in-c-cross-platform it may help you.
Good luck

Comment: Read [RFC 3986 Section 5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-5) which defines how to combine and resolve URI segments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the proposal to add URI-handling to standard C++, https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3975.html, is dead and/or stuck in committee.

You therefore have to write your own or use a 3rd party - e.g., Qt has QUrl with https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#resolved

```
QUrl QUrl::resolved(const QUrl &relative) const
```

Comment: I expect this result.

Unfortunately, Qt is a very large framework. I would prefer a less complex library.

I found uriparser library: 
https://uriparser.github.io/doc/api/latest/#resolution

Unfortunately it is written in pure C - modern c ++ would be better